# ExpressJS Ajax request is getting redirected/Aborted

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make an AJAX request to one of my routes which should return some data, but I can't solve the fact that when I make an AJAX request I'm being redirected to the route I'm requesting.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Ajax:

```
var request    = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url        = 'http://localhost:3000/signin';

    var credentials = {
        email: document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value,
        password: document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value
    };

    JSON.stringify(credentials);

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if(request.status == 200) {
                if(request.readyState == 4) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            } else if(request.status == 400) {
                console.log('There was an error 400');
            } else {
                console.log('something else other than 200 was returned');
            }
        }
    }

    request.open('POST', url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    request.send(credentials);
```

Api Endpoint:

```
app.post('/signin', function(req, res) {
    request.post({
        url:'http://localhost:3000/api/authenticate',
        form: {
            email: req.body.email,
            hashed_password: req.body.password
        },
    }, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
        console.log(req.xhr);
        console.log(req.headers);
        if (err) {
            return console.error('failed:', err);
        }
        console.log('successful! ', JSON.parse(body));
        //user.token = data.token;
        res.json(JSON.parse(body));
    });
});
```

Comment: There are a number of things wrong here. You're AJAX request says it's sending application/x-www-form-urlencoded content, but you're not. You're JSON.stringifying `credentials` but you don't keep a reference to that result anywhere. And most likely what is happening in your case is that you're trying to send this request when the user submits a form, but you're not calling `preventDefault()` on the event so the browser is simply proceeding to submit the form normally and redirect you.

Comment: Thanks! I know, ignore application/x-www-form-urlencoded, it was just for testing. I do JSON.stringify to convert my object before Im sending it, isn't that the right way? I will try it out with the preventDefault function, tanks man! I will get back if the problem still stands by.

Comment: You need to `request.send(JSON.stringify(credentials))`

Comment: Thank u! You solved it. Working great, do I need to parse the response in the client or from my backend?